# awk issue (return an array from user defined function)

Tags: arrays, reference, error-handling, awk, return

I have this function (converting coordinate of an WGS84 geoid to cartesian coordinates...doesn't matter):

```
  function convert_geo_to_enu(coord_geo) { \
    xi=sqrt(1 - e*e*sin(coord_geo[1])*sin(coord_geo[2])); \
        \
        coord_enu[1]=(a/xi + coord_geo[3])*cos(coord_geo[1])*cos(coord_geo[2]); \
        print coord_enu[1] " hhh " ; \
        coord_enu[2]=(a/xi + coord_geo[3])*cos(coord_geo[1])*sin(coord_geo[2]); \
        coord_enu[3]=(a*(1-e*e)/xi0 + coord_geo[3])*sin(coord_geo[1]); \
    \
    return coord_enu \   # <-- here comes the problem
  } \


problem --> mawk: line 64: illegal reference to array coord_enu
```

What is the problem to return as an array? Is there any different syntax?

I could use:

```
  function convert_geo_to_enu(coord_geo, coord_enu) { \
       ...
       coord_enu[1]=...
       ...
  } \
```

or even:

```
  function convert_geo_to_enu(coord_geo) { \
       ...
       coord_enu[1]=...
       ...
  } \
```

and then just use the variable `coord_enu` as a global?

But it looks better with usage of return statement (esp. for me)

Comment: remove all the line continuation chars. they're not needed, [may cause problems](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12349873/7552), and certainly hinder readability.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A little late, but here's a solution I used:

I sent a variable I wanted filled as a parameter to the function:

```
function myfunct(result, array_size) {
    for(i = 1; i <= array_size; i++) {
        result[i] = ##whatever you want
    }
}
```

then, you can treat the result variable as an array outside of the function

hope this helps someone looking for an answer

Comment: "never too late" :D!
so I can `awk "function myfunct(result,array_size){ for(i=1; i<=array_size;i++){ result[i]= i+1 }; print result[1];} BEGIN {abc = myfunct(a, 3); print a[3];}"`

thank you!

Comment: From the man page: Parameters [to functions] are  passed  by  value  if scalar and by reference if array

Answer (score 14):

Treat the array as global. AWK can't return arrays.

Comment: could you please provide a reference?

Comment: @sergj: The error message that `gawk` outputs is more informative: "attempt to use array 'coord_enu' in a scalar context". I will continue to look for documentation, but it's not explicit in the `gawk` or `mawk` manuals.

Comment: The reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Pass-By-Value_002fReference.html