# awk embedded script issue (unexpected character '\')

Tags: bash, syntax, floating-point, awk, escaping

I use an embedded awk code in a shell script:

I have some variable assignments at the BEGIN part of it:

```
\
BEGIN { FS=","; OFS=","; service_not="false"; end_of_line="\n"; is_setup_gps="false"; \
  \
  a=6378137.0 ; \
  b=6356752.3142 ; \
  f=(a-b)/a ; \
  e=sqrt(f*(2-f)) ; \
} \
\
```

So I need '\' at the end of each line (to have an entire awk script embedded in .sh).

BUT: for the lines: a=...; b=...; f=...; the '\' causing errors...: mawk: 57: unexpected character '\'

Why?

UPD: Embedding of awk in the bash script:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 ... all shell commands ...
 mawk '... ; \
 ... ; \
 ... ; \
 ' file_to_parse
```

Comment: How do you embed the awk code into the shell script? In a HERE document? In quotes?

Comment: See [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/wrapper.html) on how to embed awk in bash. No need for the backslash-plague-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quotes around the AWK script protect the newlines. No backslashes are necessary within them.