# Returning an Associative Array from an awk function

Tags: awk

I would like to return an Associative Array from a function.  How can I go about doing this ?

Comment: Do you mean all the keys and values? Just do `for (key in array) print key, array[key]`

Comment: I mean calling a function return an associative array `myarray = myfunc()`.

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/12350254/9462095

Comment: All arrays in awk are global.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [awk issue (return an array from user defined function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349546/awk-issue-return-an-array-from-user-defined-function)

Comment: Reading the links I cannot use `return array`.  Instead I have to use a variable which in an associative array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treating the variable a as an array (b,c,d) outside of the function

```
$ awk '
     function myArray1(a, str){ split(str, a, " ") } 
     function myArray2(a, s){ for(i=1;i<=s;i++) a[i]=i*i }
     function myArray3(a){ a["foo"] = 100; a["bar"] = 200 }
     
     BEGIN {
           myArray1(b, "foo bar"); 
           print b[2]
           myArray2(c, 3); 
           print c[3]
           myArray3(d); 
           print d["bar"]
}'

bar
9
200
```